# Path issue with wkhtmltopdf.exe to convert HTML file to PDF

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, webforms, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` to convert HTML file into PDF document on a link Button
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

When User Click on a link Button it runs the following code as shown below code in pass file path as an argument ProcessStartInfo. THis code works fine in Following Scenarios only

Taking Into consideration that website is hosted on Domain http://www.xyz.net/

1. When i mention path as `http://demo.XYZ.net/` It works fine
2. When i mention path as `http://www.XYZ.net/` It doesn't work
3. In-case of local-host it works fine if path is `http://localhost:51005/XYZ/`or `http://web:8080/`

For this to work properly we need to give the website full trust level & i am not sure why code doesn't run  i give it the same domain path if i create put `PrintArticle.aspx` if i create a sub domain then it will work fine. I am nost sure if this is a security problem or what

Code Below

```
protected void lnkbtnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ConvertURLToPDF();
    try
    {
        string url = "PrintArticle.aspx?articleID=" + Request["articleID"] + "&download=yes&Language=" + Request["Language"];

        //string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", "http://demo.XYZ.net/" + url); //Works
        //string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", "http://www.xyz.net/" + url); Doesnt work
        //string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", url);

        string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", "http://localhost:51005/XYZ/" + url); //Works

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"), args)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] buffer = proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output);
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Error Message in case file is on same domain

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /PrintArticle.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the following statement

```
var url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/PrintArticle.aspx?articleID=" + Request["articleID"] + "&download=yes&Language=" + Request["Language"];
```

Now it is working fine i am not sure what it doesn't work when i specify the file path.

Answer (score 0):

output variable contains empty string
my code as follows:
     try
        {
            string url=Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +"/PrintQuickPrescription.aspx?DoctorId=" + DoctorID + "&DispnID=" + DispnID + "&ApptID=" + ApptID + "&PatientID=" + PatientID;
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

```
        string args = string.Format("\"{0}\" - ", "http://localhost:50013/DPMNewWeb/"+url);
        //string  args="http://localhost:50013/DPMNewWeb/PrintQuickPrescription.aspx";

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath("~\\Bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe"), args)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };
        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        proc.Start();

        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        byte[] buffer = proc.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output);
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();



        //byte[] fileContent = GeneratePDFFile();
        //GeneratePDFFile();
        //if (fileContent != null)
        //{
        //    Response.Clear();
        //    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //    Response.AddHeader("content-length", fileContent.Length.ToString());
        //    Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
        //    Response.End();
        //}
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```